# how to find where a mouse event come from?

Tags: c++, c, windows, mouse

Is there any way to figure out where did a mouse event come from?
I mean, if I code a C/C++ program on Windows, and get a mouse click event on it, how can I find if this event come from a mouse driver, a touchpad, or if it was send by an application (mouse event simulation by sending appropriate message like WM_LBUTTONDOWN).

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: which GUI API are talking about?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to know, certainly it's not contained in the message data.

Comment: look at this [entry in microsoft forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-hardware/is-the-mouse-event-source-information-coming-from/552578ef-a881-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5?msgId=cf9fba51-ac81-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5)

Comment: windows's official GUI (the one you have when using vc++ with MFC). But it probably doesn't matter. I think it's more related to the kernel.

Comment: Why would you care about the source of the event?

Comment: I'm working on a poker bot (see my web site), and I'm currently send mouse event to the poker application to control the mouse/keyboard. I don't want to be detected as bot by the poker software, and the mouse behavior is a way to detect bot. (do we click on the same pixel ? do we have human like mouse move ? and ... I was wondering if they can also detect if the event was sent from an application. (in this case, I would program a mouse driver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible for an application in user mode - mouse events generally don't provide documented info on event source. There is the way to obtain some message extra info by Win32 API function [GetMessageExtraInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but there is no safe way to interpret this data. It is very device specific, undocumented and never guaranteed to ever present.

To solve this task you need to develop your own [Mouse Filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) basing on Windows DDK sample.

Its callback has input parameter [`MOUSE_INPUT_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - structure containing mouse event info. There is the field `UnitId`:

> **UnitId** Specifies the unit number of the mouse device. A mouse device name has the format `\Device\PointerPortN`, where the suffix N is the unit number of the device. For example, a device, whose name is `\Device\PointerPort0`, has a unit number of zero, and a device, whose name is `\Device\PointerPort1`, has a unit number of one.

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState` doesn't give you any information on mouse input source. And it is affected by `mouse_event` function.

Answer (score 0):

GetAsyncKeyState function can be used to check if the button was pressed, and unfortunately SendInput cannot trick this function.
So you can simulate a mouse click, but the program can check if the button was really pressed.

So creating your own mouse driver is better.
I needed a safe way so simulate mouse/keyboard behavior for my bot, and I wrote a detailled article on my blog http://poker-botting.blogspot.fr/2012/11/how-to-simulate-mouse-and-keyboard.html

Comment: That's not correct. Use `mouse_event()` instead of `SendInput()` to affect `GetAsyncKeyState()` result: `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0); short bstate = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON);` `bstate` always will have most significant bit set here.

Comment: ok, but in msdn they say that mouse_event is superseded, and tell use to Use SendInput instead. But well, it's doesn"t matter as long as it will be available. thanks for your response