# Determining (programmatically) who controls the mouse on a PC using C# or C++

Tags: c#, c++, windows, mouse

Is there a way to determine who is controlling the mouse (and which mouse) on a PC programmatically?  I recently installed LogMeIn (logmein.com) and wanted to know if it's possible to (1) tell within a program if the mouse is being clicked/moved by the direct user or by a remote user, (2) write a stand-alone program that simply shows mouse events (on any application) and whether or not the mouse event was generated by a local or remote user. I am somewhat familiar with Win32 hooks, but don't think that they can give this sort of information.  Regarding (1) it would seem like a common request.  I.e. "Only allow user to complete button presses related to password change if he is local..."  or something like that.

Of secondary importance (just academic interest actually) is the question of telling whether the local user is using the mouse or the trackpad.

Comment: As per the last part of your question I suppose you would use something like this to detect if a Touchpad or Mouse or Both is active on the computer. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272

Comment: Thanks CodeCamper, I'll check it out.  Initially glancing at DevCon, I don't see how to use it to determine which mouse is in control.  It looks like you can use it to list all the mouse devices.  And of course, I don't think it will help with the problem of figuring out if  someone is controlling things through LogMeIn (as you pointed out).  Thanks!

Comment: Since posting, I found this link on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622312/how-to-find-where-a-mouse-event-come-from?rq=1   The claim in the accepted answer is that it can only be done (reliably) by creating your own mouse driver.  Sounds like quite a bit of work!

Comment: Dave perhaps you can unreliably determine if the mouse is from the local machine based on the smoothness of motion. I notice with Teamviewer the mouse has a sort of signature motion on the local machine that is different from the standard smooth mouse motion. So perhaps the locations are updating more pixels apart vs. the local machine which has a much higher resolution of motion. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since posting, I came across this post which basically answers the question.

[C# Get Mouse handle (GetRawInputDeviceInfo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584280/c-sharp-get-mouse-handle-getrawinputdeviceinfo)

I'd add that for those of you who want to use WPF instead of WinForms (as the example above uses), check out ComponentDispatcher.ThreadFilterMessage (for WPF) or IMessageFilter (Windows Forms).

I wrote a couple of programs based on the above posting (one is basically the posting above with some minor additions and the other is a WPF (as opposed to WinForms)).  If I can figure out GitHub I'll post all the code and add a comment here.  But the posting above definitely gives you all you need.

Comment: Can u share some example using WPF please

Comment: Hi Jesus.    It's been a long time since I worked on this.  For what it's worth, checkout:   https://github.com/andrewdwalker/RemoteMouseExample

Answer (score 1):

you can hook the device API's of windows that you want to get the information from, then if the mouse moves the api is probably not called when the user movers the mouse, but if logmein does then it probably calls some SetMousePointerPos-like C WinAPI.